# How to print and load an array with random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random

I need to display a list of 10 random double numbers in order and spaced out in a row. This is what I have so far:

```
double [] array;
    array = new double [10];
    for (int i = 0 ; i <array.length; i++) {
     array[i] =  Math.random()*((100 - 0)-1);
        printArray(array);
    }


}
public static void printArray(double [] array) {
    for (double eachElement: array){
        System.out.printf("%f." , eachElement);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to print the array after filling all of it, not after filling each cell:

```
double[] array;
array = new double[10];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = Math.random() * ((100 - 0) - 1);
}
printArray(array);
```

Comment: Thank you!! I new it was something simple!

Comment: You're welcome, but there's no need to post thank yous. Just accept the answer if it solved the problem.